# Is there a way to see how small caps of an OTF should look like?

Tags: pdftex, otftotfm

I am in the dilemma of convertig an OTF for the use with PDFlatex and I am making good progress with the German description at https://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?67058-(verh%E4ltmism%E4ssig)-einfache-Schriftinstallation-unter-Miktex-2-8 so far. The font I try to convert is a corporate font, which is not publicly available and hence I am sorry that I can only provide analysis, not the actual piece of evidence. ;-)

The conversion of normal and italics in 5 font weights went great. However now there seems to be an issue with the small caps of my font. Using `otfinfo -f $FONTNAME$.otf` results in:

```
aalt    Access All Alternates
case    Case-Sensitive Forms
dnom    Denominators
frac    Fractions
kern    Kerning
liga    Standard Ligatures
numr    Numerators
ordn    Ordinals
pnum    Proportional Figures    Proportionale Zahlen
sinf    Scientific Inferiors
smcp    Small Capitals  Small caps
sups    Superscript Tabellenzahlen
tnum    Tabular Figures
```

So it seems small caps are available, but converting it with `otftotfm -n $FONTNAME$-LightSC --vendor=Fontvendor --typeface=Fontface -f liga -f kern -f onum -f smcp -e texnansx --map-file=./output/$FONTNAME$.map --directory=./output/ $FONTNAME$.otf` gives me the binary exact same vf and tfm files. To confirm, that my commands are right, I replace `$FONTNAME$.otf` with `LinBiolinum_R.otf` because I know, this font actually has small caps.

So my question is, is there a way (with an editor or simple tool), so see how each character in my font looks, to see whether small caps are just mapped to lower case letters? If anybody has an idea, what else I might be wrong, please tell me!

Comment: Why don't you use autoinst?

Comment: ```autoinst``` creates the same issue, the font does not have small caps, but regular small letters when using ```\textsc{}```, hence I nailed it down to ```otftotfm``` and ```otfinfo```.

Comment: Can you use the font with lualatex? Does it show small caps?

Comment: I tried ```\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{$FONTNAME$.otf}
\begin{document}
Test

\textsc{Test}

\end{document}``` and both words are printed as Test, not TEST with small caps.

Comment: I think I have an idea what the issue is. Can it be, that ```otftotfm``` is just making an educated guess about availability of small caps? In Biolinium I found lots of glyphs that are called ```*.sc``` and in my font there is only ```commaaccent.sc```, nothing else. So maybe this misleads otftotfm to think, it supports small caps, while it actually only has one character.

Comment: I don't think that otftotfm guesses, it looks at the declare features in the font, but a font can lie about the features it actually supports.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105987/discussion-between-tobibs-and-ulrike-fischer).